# Generate fields from a sql script

Tags: html, sql, jsp

I need to generate HTML fields when a user registers a SQL script.

Ex: A user registers the SQL query:

```
select * from user where name = ?, age = ?
```

Then, when the user selects this script, two input text elements appread: name and age. Then the user can do the search...

Any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm using JSP.. one friend show me this suggestion: WHERE CDFTB_UNIDADE.CODUNIDADE IN (Name @TEXT@S) but i dont undesrtand it ... lol

Comment: This has nothing to do with sql, From the front end application you have to run this query then do whatever you want to do from there, for example js, php, asp.net etc..

Comment: If the user is defining the SQL then they should also define the parameter names and you can have a tokenised query. However this does look like a solution vulnerable to a SQL injection attack so if its an Internet app you may want to consider a more rigorous approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by stating the, hopefully, obvious: ***Allowing your users to enter an arbitrary SQL statement and executing that is a recipe for disaster***. You have to use a really *really* good parser and limit the queries to a carefully designated subset that they are save to execute and limit the extent to which your users can query the database using appropriate permissions on the database server.

That being said, to actually solve your problem you will still need to parse the SQL query and identify the parameters in the query. If you've solved the previous problem, you should presumably already have a good parser so identifying the tokens "name" and "age" as input parameters should have been accomplished already.

Then it's really only a matter of generating HTML input elements for each one of the tokens. Of course, for that you need to use a programming language - either on the server side or the client side. Choosing to go with the client side is a bad idea because of the same reason as stated in the first paragraph. So, your best bet is to produce the HTML fragment on the server-side.

Using a server-side programming language you can then easily generate the HTML code.

What server-side technology are you using? Is it ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby on Rails, JSP etc.?

Given this high-level answer you should be able to produce a narrowed-down question.

Comment: Hi .. I'm using JSP.. one friend show me this suggestion: 
WHERE
     CDFTB_UNIDADE.CODUNIDADE IN (<PD>Name @TEXT@S</PD>)
but i dont undesrtand ... lol

Comment: @Shermano, I don't understand what your friend has suggested there. But if you update your question and include that and as much information as possible someone else may be able to help you. You only get good responses if you make the effort to write good questions!